# In Spring MVC, how can I set the mime type header when using @ResponseBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a Spring MVC Controller that returns a JSON String and I would like to set the mimetype to application/json. How can I do that?

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="foo/bar")
@ResponseBody
public String fooBar(){
    return myService.getJson();
}
```

The business objects are already available as JSON strings, so using `MappingJacksonJsonView` is not the solution for me. `@ResponseBody` is perfect, but how can I set the mimetype?

Comment: using spring 3.2 and its new testing feature ... is there no solution without using ResponseEntity ?

Comment: Use HttpHeaders.setContentType  - here are some [examples of how to use it](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders/setContentType)

Comment: @drorw that was introduced years after this question :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would consider to refactor the service to return your domain object rather than JSON strings and let Spring handle the serialization (via the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` as you write). As of Spring 3.1, the implementation looks quite neat:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    method = RequestMethod.GET
    value = "/foo/bar")
@ResponseBody
public Bar fooBar(){
    return myService.getBar();
}
```

Comments:

First, the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or the `@EnableWebMvc` must be [added](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) to your application config.

Next, the [produces](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation is used to specify the content type of the response. Consequently, it should be set to [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) (or `"application/json"`).

Lastly, Jackson must be added so that any serialization and de-serialization between Java and JSON will be handled automatically by Spring (the Jackson dependency is detected by Spring and the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` will be under the hood).

Comment: This answer should be number one, let Spring do the work for you!!

Comment: According to the javadoc, the purpose of property *produces* is to match the *Accept* header of the request. This explains why the value of *produces* is a list of values. Therefore, *produces* is not a reliable mean to add any response headers. According to the javadoc, it has nothing to do with response headers.

Answer (score 124):

Use `ResponseEntity` instead of `ResponseBody`. This way you have access to the response headers and you can set the appropiate content type. According to the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity):

> The `HttpEntity` is similar to
>   `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody`.
>   Besides getting access to the request
>   and response body, `HttpEntity` (and the
>   response-specific subclass
>   `ResponseEntity`) also allows access to
>   the request and response headers

The code will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/fooBar")
public ResponseEntity<String> fooBar2() {
    String json = "jsonResponse";
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: hi, I want to return a serialized object but using your method I have a problem, it doesn't compile because it says: HttpHeaders is abstract can not be instantiated.... can you explain me as well how you woud do this having to return the serialization of an object? now it works fine if not using ResponseEntity

Comment: @Lince81 org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders is not an abstract class (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html). See if your import is correct and your libraries are updated.

Comment: @Lince81 the point of the example is returning an already serialized object as a String while setting a different Content-Type. If you want Spring to serialize an Object (as XML, JSON, etc) use @ResponseBody and configure the appropiate MessageConverters (see link in the answer)

Comment: I needed a way to return a string that was already in JSON format and tell spring not to mess with it. This works great.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Spring MVC 3.1 allows you to specify a value for "produces" in the RequestMapping. So you can still use @ResponseBody, but you need @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/fooBar", produces="application/json").

Comment: With this approach you can have the same method return different content-types, something that you cannot do with Spring's "produces". Also, this is the least intrusive i.e. you don't have to create/ instantiate your own MessageConverters.

Answer (score 7):

You may not be able to do it with @ResponseBody, but something like this should work:

```
package xxx;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class FooBar {
  @RequestMapping(value="foo/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void fooBar(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.write(myService.getJson().getBytes());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setContentLength(out.size());
    response.getOutputStream().write(out.toByteArray());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: would he need to write to the response, or just setting the header would do?

Comment: great answer. If the mime type is dynamic, then the byte array must surely be dynamic as well, so it makes sense to just write the byte array without the magic of @ResponseBody. The only revise would be to write the OutputStream directly, instead of loading it into memory (out.toByteArray).

Comment: @JamesWatkins You need to load the JSON into memory to be able to calculate the content length. If your JSON object is reasonable small (and they usually should be!) this should be no concern.

Comment: I think the true nature of the question is: "How do I set the mime type and send a non-HTML response at the same time?" I could have a very large file that I want to stream to the client. Also, Content Length is optional and there are other ways to derive it (from database, etc).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible. There appears to be an open Jira for it:

[SPR-6702: Explicitly set response Content-Type in @ResponseBody](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6702)

Comment: It's fixed in Spring 3.1 - use `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,  value = "foo/bar", produces = "application/json")`, see [SPR-7353](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7353)

Answer (score 3):

Register `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` as the message converter and return the object directly from the method.

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="webBindingInitializer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer"/>
  </property>
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and the controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="foo/bar")
public @ResponseBody Object fooBar(){
    return myService.getActualObject();
}
```

This requires the dependency `org.springframework:spring-webmvc`.

Comment: Yes, probably a best practice, but as I wrote my objects are already JSON strings and I just want to write them out with the correct mime type.

Comment: What are the maven dependencies for the beans you are referencing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, apart from `response.setContentType(..)`

Comment: Which means I must define a parameter of type HttpServletResponse?

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work (mime type was still text/html)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd strange. What is the "Accept" header of your request?

Answer (score -2):

My version of reality.  Loading a HTML file and streaming to the browser.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UIController {

    @RequestMapping(value="index", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public @ResponseBody String GetBootupFile() throws IOException  {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("MainPage.html");
        String fileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(resource.getFile());
        return fileContents;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are aware that Spring MVC can [serve static resources out of the box](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)?

Comment: Not only is that a lot more work than needed, but you are breaking a lot of other things Spring can automatically take care of and manage for you, as well as opening up security issues, and other failure points.