# Java AJAX Variable Passing

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a java file by which I want to pass map something like : { id: 5, GPA: 5} to my jsp file using AJAX. I am using following code for this:

In my JAVA file:

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
            jsonResult.put("id", "5");
            jsonResult.put("GPA", "5");

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jsonResult.toString());
}
```

In jsp file:
--some extJS code--

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url :'assertion.htm',
            method  : 'POST',
            params: {
                    existingRule : nameField.getRawValue()
            },
            scope   : this,
            success: function ( response ) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
```

response.responseText is printing entire jsp file instead of printing id:5, GPA:5
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Retagged because you seem to be using Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
            jsonResult.put("id", "5");
            jsonResult.put("GPA", "5");

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jsonResult.toString());
}
```

This won't compile, you are missing a return statement.

This seems to be a Spring MVC controller, judging by the `ModelAndView` return type. My guess is that you are returning a JSP view instead of the JSON Object you want to return. See [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471584/in-spring-mvc-how-can-i-set-the-mime-type-header-when-using-responsebody) for how to return a JSON Object from Spring MVC.

Comment: I am sorry but I have added return statement 
 ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("AssertionScreen","AssertRules", "A");
return mav;

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything and this is correct so change it to void:

```
protected void handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
            jsonResult.put("id", "5");
            jsonResult.put("GPA", "5");

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jsonResult.toString());
}
```