# Optional Request Header in Spring Rest Service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest

I'm using Spring Restful web service & having request body with request header as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mykey", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="applicaton/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader("Auth") String authorization)  {
try {
    ....
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
}
}
```

I want to pass one more optional request header called "X-MyHeader". How do I specify this optional request header in Spring rest service?

Also, how do I pass this same value in response header??
Thanks!

UPDATE: I just found that I can set required=false in request header, so one issue is resolved. Now, the only issue remaining is how do I set the header in the response??

Comment: It deserves to notice that `@RequestHeader` is only for original headers in request, not ones added through interceptor or filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is answered here:
[In Spring MVC, how can I set the mime type header when using @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471584/in-spring-mvc-how-can-i-set-the-mime-type-header-when-using-responsebody)

Here is a code sample from: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  String requestHeader = requestEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("MyRequestHeader");
  byte[] requestBody = requestEntity.getBody();
  // do something with request header and body

  HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
  return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Use `required=false` in your `@RequestHeader`:

```
@PostMapping("/mykey")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(
  @RequestBody String body, 
  @RequestHeader(value = "Auth", required = false) String authorization)  {}
```