# Spring REST view resolution - unsupported content type

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, rest

When posting an `XML` object `Foo` to `/foo.xml` I can't get *path extension* view resolution to kick in, but get the error

> Unsupported content type: text/plain

Which is a result of not posting any `Content-Type` headers. But `favorPathExtention` should remove that need. Any idea why it doesn't?

---

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo.xml", method=ADD, produces="application/xml")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody Foo add(@RequestBody Foo foo)  {
    return foo;
}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="my.pkg.controller")
public class RestWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(...));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
            .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
            .useJaf(false)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
}
```

Comment: shoudn't just /foo should work instead of /foo.xml in your request mapping?

Comment: I need explicit mappings `/foo.json`, `/foo.xml` and so on since the `json` object is different from the `xml` object.

Comment: One (less than ideal) solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471584/in-spring-mvc-how-can-i-set-the-mime-type-header-when-using-responsebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of content negotiation.

Content negotiation is for how the response will be generated, not how the request will be parsed.

You get

> Unsupported content type: text/plain

because, with `@RequestBody`, there are no registered`HttpMessageConverter` instances that can read the default request content-type of `application/octet-stream` (or maybe your client uses `text/plain`). This all happens in the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` which handles generating an argument for the parameter annotated with `@RequestBody`.

If you're going to send XML or JSON in your request body, set the `Content-Type`.

---

As for the content negotiation, with your config and request, the `DispatcherServlet` will attempt to generate a response with content type `application/xml`. Because of `@ResponseBody`, you will need an `HttpMessageConverter` capable of producing such content. Your `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` should be enough. If it isn't, you can write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `text/plain` as a supported media type to the message converters, something like

```
@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> jsonTypes = new ArrayList<>(jsonConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
    jsonTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jsonTypes);
    converters.add(jsonConverter);
}
```