# Spring - Unable To Send Error Message For API Returning ByteArrayResource

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have an rest API in a Spring for generating and downloading a PDF file. The controller definitation is as follows -

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/foo/bar/pdf",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@Nullable
public ByteArrayResource downloadPdf(@RequestParam int userId) {
    byte[] result = null;
    ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = null;

    result = service.generatePdf(userId);

    if (result != null) {
        byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(result);
    }

    return byteArrayResource;
}
```

I use Jackson for JSON handling JSON and have an Exception handler ControllerAdvice. The problem is when this API generates an exception and I return a custom exception class (contains message and one additional field).

As I already specified `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` this custom class is also attempted to be converted to an octet stream by Spring, which it fails at and produces `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`.

I tried solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228512/spring-how-to-choose-response-type-on-run-time) Stackoverflow question, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30229483/1589165) but it still fails. This solution, along with other changes suggests removing `produces` part from `@RequestMapping` but when I debugged into `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getProducibleMediaTypes` it only detects application/json as available response media type.

**tl;dr** 
How can I have this API return the file on success and correctly return custom exception class's JSON representation on error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with similar code. I just removed the `produces` attribute  from my `@PostMapping` and I was able to return the file or the json (when the api have some error):

```
@Override
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generate(
        @PathVariable long id
) {
    Result result = service.find(id);

    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .contentLength(result.getSize())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(result.getFile()));
}
```

When some error occur, I had a `@ExceptionHandler` to care of that:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleApiException(ApiException ex) {
    ApiErrorResponse error = new ApiErrorResponse(ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, ex.getHttpStatus());
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Removing produces solved my issue.

Comment: Same, removing 'produces' solves mine too. But isn't this a disadvantage since we are removing content-negotiation functionality here by removing the @Produces annotation? I am referring to this answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182697/2605210

Answer (score 1):

Try implements your action as

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/foo/bar/pdf",
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<byte[]> downloadPdf(@RequestParam int userId) {
 byte[] result = service.generatePdf(userId);

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

 if (result != null) {
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=export.pdf");
    headers.setContentLength(result.length);

    return new HttpEntity(result, headers);
}

 return new HttpEntity<>(header)
}
```

About exception handling for example you may throw `YourCustomError` and in controller annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` annotate a method with `@ExceptionHandler(YourCustomError.class)` and work with it.